# Simple Progress Bar that looks like this

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I‘m a not very advanced in coding. I‘m looking for an easy way to create an progress bar with html & css that looks like this (no animation needed).

Can anybody help me with a code?

Thank you Mags

[image]

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Stack Overflow isn't a "give me the code" site. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Css and HTML

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:0 auto;
}
 
.skill {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
 
.skill > p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #1a1716;
    margin: 0;
}
 
.skill:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #959595;
    bottom: 0;
}
 
.skill-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background:#f4392f;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
 
.skill-bar span {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 5px solid #f4392f;
    top: -30px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
}
 
.skill-bar {
    position: relative;
}
 
.skill1 .skill-count1 {
    right: 0;
}
 
.skill1 {
    width: 95%;
}
 
.skill2 {
    width: 85%;
}
 
.skill2 .skill-count2 {
    right: 0;
}
 
.skill3{
   width: 75%;
}
 
.skill3 .skill-count3 {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="how-title">CSS3 Skill Progress bar</h2>
    <br><br>
    <div class="skill">
        <p>HTML5</p>
        <div class="skill-bar skill1">
            <span class="skill-count1">95%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
        <p>CSS3</p>
        <div class="skill-bar skill2">
            <span class="skill-count2">85%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
        <p>JQUERY</p>
        <div class="skill-bar skill3">
            <span class="skill-count3">75%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't actually look like what the question required.

Comment: Ohhh.. U need exact same desing??

Comment: Yes, sorry for not sharing my code. I've use a similar html & css code as shown above. But I'm not able to get the thin lines with the circle

Comment: You can edit your question!